# Name provider for Aggregates in CQRS+ES powered solution, emit NameChangedEvent once for all child objects

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a CQRS+ES solution that takes some Events to change AggregateName. Because I have multiple Aggregates responsible for holding different info on domain events. To date, I have a simple naming strategy, using convention (main aggregate name as a source, domain objects as a source).

Example: main aggregate name `SolutionAggregate` after using convention (remove "Aggregate") is "`Solution`"

Domain object for collections: `SolutionItem` (main aggregate name + `Item`)

Collection commands: (`commandType` + `AggregateName` + `Item`):

```
AddSolutionItem
RemoveSolutionItem
UpdateSolutionItem
```

As you would probably know, renaming of each of these objects is quite complicated down in the flow, when a lot of objects are created.

I Was thinking on some sort of `NamingProvider` and `NamingConsumer` pattern (don't mix it up with common design patterns please).

I have tried numerous things, but can't really come up with solution on how to implement this, so that `INamingProvider` ID is distributed accross all commands within Aggregate/DomainObject contexts.

When an `INamingProvider`  aka. Aggregate or DomainObject is created, I would store it's Name value in a repository. Then when next object (which uses the Name in a convention like `blahObjectNameItem` or `blahAggeragteNameItem`) is created. I would store `NameProviderId` as an element of Aggregate.

Then when materialising above objects, I would just check their `NamingProviderId`, fetch NameProvider and give them a name, building something like `operation` + `NameProviderName` + `Suffix` ie. `GetSolutionItem` where `Get` is an operation, `Solution` is aggregate name and `Item` is a suffix.

For the INFO: I need to generate CODE based on above aggregates. That's why I need NAMING solution. Each class has it's own name, but all of them are based on single Aggregate.

Just imagine, that I have 100 classes based on single aggregate. I want to change it's name, what would influence all classes below. Complexity of going through all objects and changing their names, would be too costly.

That's why I'm on the look for a better solution.

**UPDATE 1:**

Just o visualize number of objects below an Aggregate, let's say that you would have following children:

Base Aggregate: `SolutionAggregate`

AggregateName: `Solution` (because of convention, I remove `Aggregate` from name)

Object1: `CreateSolutionCommand`

Object2: `SolutionCreatedEvent`

Object3: `SolutionItem`

Object4: `CreateSolutionItem`

Object5: `SolutionItemCreatedEvent`

... and so on ...

You should see the pattern.

Comment: Code generation for domain objects seems very wrong

Comment: This sounds like a compatibility nightmare; I think it's supposed to be painful.

Comment: @constantin-galbenu It would be wrong, if it wasn't a requirement.

Comment: Item is a member of a collection, so how it's not "ubiquitous language" ? I don't really care about some sort of out of the world conventions, but actual ideas for solving problems. Naming of items is strictly down to creators.

Comment: What's a 'solution' in your domain, and why would the name of that concept change?

Comment: I'm confused in your question about whether you are talking about changing a name field in an aggregate (e.g. the name of a solution), which should be trivial, or about renaming a class in your code, along with all of its events, which is complex and causes versioning headaches, and is only needed if your ubiquitous language is changed by your domain experts for some reason.

Comment: @Drakkonite *"Just imagine, that I have 100 classes based on single aggregate"* - is it the case in your actual domain model? If not, YAGN such a complicated renaming system. If it is, then until proven otherwise, there's something wrong with your design.